# How to work on a intelliJ project in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, playframework, sbt

I am trying to work on an Java project began by someone else on intelliJ, but I usually use VS Code.

We are using SBT, with play Framework and Gradle. And we are coding in java, not in scala.

I have read few documentations and tried different extensions configurations (extension pack for java, SBT, scala metals), but i am still having the same problems : almost 400 imports errors like this one :

```
"The import play cannot be resolve"
```

(not only for play, but also Http, JSon, Inject...).

I've tried different things to fix it : clean java language server workspace, removing manually the the same files, and even changed my settings to :

```
`{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
  "java.saveActions.organizeImports": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "autoimport.showNotifications": true,
  "files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/target": true
  },
  "java.format.settings.url": "eclipse-formatter.xml"
}
`
```

Any ideas about extensions I forgot to download or anything that could help to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether all required dependencies are correctly included in configuration files such as `build.gradle`.

[image]

Then check that all necessary plugins are installed, including the most basic [Java extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) and other plugins that your project requires. Here is the [starting documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) you can read.

If you're still having trouble, try creating a new project in VS Code and import your existing code into it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

It look likes my problem is coming from referenced libraies. Actually there is nothing in it. I've tried to import some manually and it worked (now i don't have any problems with javax imports (only 350 errors left !). But i don't understand why it isn't importing those directly (given that my classpath in my root.json file seems to be good).